# Veins: Error: unable to resolve host/address 'sumo.dlr.de'

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using Veins-4a2 and Sumo-0.22.0. Since many months working with this platform, today I tried to launch a new simulation but I got this error in the terminal:

```
<stderr><![CDATA[Warning: Environment variable SUMO_HOME is not set,
schema resolution will use slow website lookups.
Error: unable to resolve host/address 'sumo.dlr.de'
In file 'myFile.poly.xml'
```

and this error in Omnet++:

```
<!> Error in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) 

RSUExampleScenario.manager (id=6) at event #1, t=0: Attempted to read 

past end of byte buffer.
```

Note that the environment variable SUMO_HOME is well set. I could not understand the error, can anyone helps me to fix it please?

Here is myFile.poly.xml:

https://www.transfernow.net/ddl/myFile

Answer (score 0):

Sumo tries to validate `myFile.poly.xml` with its schema definition. I guess, the value of `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` in `myFile.poly.xml` is set to some url which includes `sumo.dlr.de`.

Apparently, http://sumo.dlr.de/ is down since a couple of days at least, hence this won't work. Try to use `http://sumo.sourceforge.net/xsd/polyconvertConfiguration.xsd` as value instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  I tried to use the new url but I got this error:  <stderr><![CDATA[Error: no declaration found for element 'additional'
 In file 'myFile.poly.xml. How can I fix it please?

Comment: Knowing that myFile.poly.xml contains this line:   <additional xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.sourceforge.net/xsd/polyconvertConfiguration.xsd">

Comment: I tried the poly file from Veins 4a2 with Sumo 0.22 and it worked. I also tried the same file with your schema definition and it worked, too. Please edit your question and post you poly file.

Comment: I tried with Veins-4a2 which I used since many years but it does not work, I edited my post by adding a link to my file.

Comment: I added your file to erlangen.launchd.xml in Veins 4a2 (`<copy file="myFile.poly.xml" />`) and ran the example simulation. Sumo 0.22 loaded the file without errors. Maybe your environment variable is not set after all. Please do `echo $SUMO_HOME` to verify that it is indeed set.

Comment: It's weird, I tested my file with erlangen example in Veins-4a2 but it does not work. It shows me the same error:   <stderr><![CDATA[Error: no declaration found for element 'additional'